# Multiple Apache Auth User Files

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, virtualhost, http-basic-authentication

I have multiple vhosts on a host running apache. It is a test system and I would like to give users "basic authentication" access to their sites.

For this I have a vhost file with basic auth configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName demo.com
    ServerAlias test.demo.com
    DocumentRoot /filepath/to/demo.com/public_html
    <Location />
        Deny from all
        AuthUserFile /filepath/to/demo.com-users
        AuthName authorization
        AuthType Basic
        Satisfy Any
        require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine and can be done per virtual host domain.

**Question:** For the staff I would like to set a global "auth directive" in the normal httpd.conf file that allows them to login to all vhosts in one step.

Can this be done and how?

Answer (score 1):

You could define a single password file for all your users and then create a groups file to classify them according to their virtual host permissions. You could have a special group for the staff.

Then instead of require valid-user you could use the following.

```
AuthGroupFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/groups
Require group GroupName
```

For reference you can read the *Letting more than one person in* section in  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html